Milky way from planet Earth
So every night if you look up at the stars you see the milky way band across the sky, but knowing that we travel through it and that the earth rotates, why don't we ever view away from the band "outer arms" of the milky way? Meaning that surely we don't always view just the milky way center every night all year round. I appreciate responses

The Earth's spin axis is inclined away from the Galactic center at about 120 degrees. That means we can and do view away from the center. In fact, if you live in the northern hemisphere then you are never looking towards the center of the Milky Way at any time of year. It may just be above the horizon during the summer months.  On the contrary, those in the southern hemisphere see towards the Galactic center more readily and it is most visible in the southern winter.
The Sun is located in the disk of the Milky Way. Our view outwards or inwards through the disk is limited to about 9,000 light years in either direction due to clouds of obscuring dust that are concentrated there. The Galactic center is about 25,000 light years away, so we actually do not see the Galactic center at all from either hemisphere.
Because the density of stars and gas falls relatively slowly with Galactic radius, that means we have a similar view of the Milky Way in all directions through the disk and the Milky Way appears as a complete band running right around the sky.

There is less physics and a lot of geometry.
We are inside the Milky way.
Imagine you are in a stadium, neither in the first nor the last seats, during a popular sports event. This is a good analogy for the Solar system place in the Milky way.
You can look everywhere around and see other visitors. There are no much people above or below you.
Ok, there are differences. The Milky way is not this much flat so we see some stars in all directions.
Milky way is visibly not an uniform band either - the stellar distribution is pretty much uneven and we see features that rotate together with the whole celestial sphere.
Because of the timescales involved, the Milky way looks fixed in relation to the constelations and its center is always in Sagittarius.
